# WPF form inside windows form window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, rss, integration

I want to make this Info.xaml file which is inside my windows form application to be loaded in the my current form but to fill it entirely on the click of the button.

This is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="RssDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="RSS Demo" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="576" Width="521">
    <Window.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE2E2E2" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.Background>

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="rssData" XPath="//item" Source="***********" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="177*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="55*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="122*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="177*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox x:Name="lstItems" Margin="3,6,3,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource rssData}}"
                 SelectedIndex="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="20" Margin="3" Source="{Binding XPath=enclosure/@url}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstItems, Path=SelectedItem}" Margin="0,0,0,5">
            <TextBlock Margin="3" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding XPath=title, Path=InnerText}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="3" Opacity="0.72" Text="{Binding XPath=pubDate}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstItems, Path=SelectedItem}" Margin="0,1,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TextBlock ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="3"
                       FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding XPath=description, Path=InnerText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Justify" Width="489" AllowDrop="False"
                       Foreground="#FF0000E7" FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" Height="352" />
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: When you say "in my current form," do you mean that you have an MDI application?

Comment: No I have only one main window.

Comment: So the WPF window is a control within your WinForms window?

Comment: yes I mean I want to load wpf window inside my form window to fill it.

Comment: I think you will probably want to convert your Window to a UserControl instead - I'm not sure that `ElementHost` will host a Window.

Comment: how to change it to control instead of window?

Comment: I have used wpf element in toolbox to add this in win form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You may use **ElementHost*** as explained here*

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2007/12/11/6740119.aspx

**Alternatively, you may look here too [if you can convert it to a usercontrol]**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745781.aspx

**If you particularly want Windows Forms opening a WPF window then read here** -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.enablemodelesskeyboardinterop.aspx

More info here -
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/442782b1-00a1-4e2e-9cc6-ae99b6699126/

Comment: Converting VB to C# shouldn't be difficult; you'll be using all the same classes and methods.

Comment: Use this for conversion - http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/